# How to improve filtering for large array of React Elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading, async-await

I have a large number of React Elements in an array. When I type in an associated text field, the React elements get filtered depending on whether the text within each one contains the typed text or not.

**Typing in the text field becomes sluggish** when filtering a large number of elements like this. Presumably this is because everything is happening on a single thread and the filtering logic is hogging the thread while it is executing and thus slowing down UI input.

*I'm presuming there must be a way to solve this in an asynchronous way in Javascript so the UI doesn't get blocked by background computational logic ?*

I've been trying a couple of `async-await` based approaches found online but nothing has worked yet.

I've created a cut down Code Sandbox of my issue here :

[image: Edit spring-dust-vbp9h]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function MyFilterTextComponent(props) {
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState("");
  const [filteredElements, setFilteredElements] = useState(props.dataToFilter);
  const { dataToFilter } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredElements(
      dataToFilter.filter(currWord => {
        return currWord.includes(filterText);
      })
    );
  }, [dataToFilter, filterText]);

  const handleFilterTextChange = event => {
    setFilterText(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label for="filterText">Filter text:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="filterText"
        name="filterText"
        onChange={handleFilterTextChange}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      {filteredElements.map(element => {
        return <Button>{element}</Button>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you would benefit from debouncing the onchange handler.  every change is invoking the handler and thus filtering the list.  I would first add some constraints,  i.e. more then 2 chars needed in input, and only invoke filter after user has stopped typing for 2 seconds etc.. that way you are not waiting for 5 previous filter operations to complete before you run  the one you want, after a user enters 6 chars.

Comment: What about extracting the filter part into a web worker?
Havent used them in react so far but seems there are [ways](https://medium.com/@dai_shi/playing-with-react-hooks-and-web-workers-2ebdf1c93dea).

Comment: Yes debouncing certainly seems to have solved my issue as per answer from @Drew Reese below

Comment: @smoothie - Certainly something I'll keep in my toolbox for future issues. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching an array of words, checking if each word contains a search key is potentially an `O(n^3)` operation.

I tried throttling/debouncing the state update functions (i.e. only trigger `setFilterText` every 250ms and `setFilteredElements` every 500ms) but this doesn't really mitigate the O(n^3) search complexity, it only delays it. I did notice significant improvement when using a div/span (even a regular button) over the MUI Button though (even without throttling/debouncing). This implies a large overhead for the Material-UI Button component.

[image: Edit filter array of words]

Comment: Nice. This has certainly solved the issue I was having. Much smoother performance now.

Comment: I had a similar type of issue and converted a button to div/span has improved a performance. I was filtering through 50k records and creating a buttons inside an <li>. Instead of button when i created a span, it improved a performance by good amount